# VBA - How to insert a row and divide data into groups?

Tags: excel, vba

I use the code below to copy my data from one sheet to another.

```
Sub Copypastemeddata()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartRow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Opgørsel")
    Set sourceCell = ws.Range("D3")  'Cell with sheet names for copying to
    StartRow = 1    'Destination row on targetSheet
    With ws
          Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets(sourceCell.Text)
         .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
         targetSheet.Range("A" & StartRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
         targetSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
End Sub
```

In the sheet I'm copying, i want to insert a row every time the value under cell "tykkelse [m]" is different and divide it under the same row if the value is the same for multiple copies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

below provides a possible solution:

```
Sub solved()

Set findfirst = Sheet1.Range("H:H").Find("tykkelse [m]")

currentvalue = findfirst.Offset(1, 0).Value

findfirst.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
With Range(Cells(findfirst.Row - 2, 1), Cells(findfirst.Row - 2, 14))
    .Merge
    .Value = currentvalue
End With

Set findfirst = Sheet1.Range("H:H").Find("tykkelse [m]")
Set findsecond = Sheet1.Range("H:H").FindNext(After:=findfirst)

Do While Intersect(findsecond, findfirst) Is Nothing

    If findsecond.Offset(1, 0).Value <> currentvalue Then
        currentvalue = findsecond.Offset(1, 0).Value
        findsecond.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
        With Range(Cells(findsecond.Row - 2, 1), Cells(findsecond.Row - 2, 14))
            .Merge
            .Value = currentvalue
        End With
    End If

    Set findsecond = Sheet1.Range("H:H").FindNext(findsecond)

Loop

End Sub
```

First, we find the first occurrence of "tykkelse [m]":

Then we store the value associated to this occurrence, and insert the row above and merge (color and alignment still to be added)

We find first occurrence again, because it has shifted, and we need it for the check below. We loop over each occurrence in column H and check if we had them all by comparing it to the first occurrence.

For each occurrence, we check if the value underneath has changed; if so, we apply the same manipulations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - When i try to run it a box comes up with "Run time error: 424 - Object required". 
- But i am thinking if your code should be a part of the one i posted?

Comment: Hi, this is probably due to my reference to sheet1.
If you add my code to the bottom of your code, you can edit `Sheet1` to `targetSheet`

Comment: It dosent Work that way - It overwrites the first one and dont divide it if the the value in "tykkelse [m]" is random - If it is 150, 75 and the 150 comes Again it will make a new one with 150 instead of copying under 150.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870763/how-to-order-multiple-copies-in-other-sheet-into-group-under-a-created-header-ro

Comment: @Jeron - When i run the macro it just paste in the same sheet instead of pasting it to other sheets as before?

Comment: When i run the code in the sheet i have my button, it just copies right there instead of copying to the other sheets.