# How to add/organize mulitple headliners/rows in another sheet, on the condition of a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this VBA and trying to learn more by watching videos on YouTubee and looking in some books and right now I'm stuck - can't come further - I hope someone will direct me to the right path or help me modifying the code.

First - I want to order/organize everytime I make a copy to the other sheet. With this code below I copy my data to the specific sheet that I want.

```
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartRow As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Opgørsel")
    Set sourceCell = ws.Range("D3")  'Cell with sheet names for copying to
    StartRow = 1    'Destination row on targetSheet
    With ws
          Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets(sourceCell.Text)
         .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
         targetSheet.Range("A" & StartRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
         targetSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```

Then everytime I make a copy, I want to create a row/headliner that comes with the copy to that specific sheet. I do that with this part of the code.

```
Set findfirst = targetSheet.Range("H:H").Find("Tykkelse [m]")
 currentvalue = findfirst.Offset(1, -4).Value & " " & findfirst.Offset(1, 0).Value
  findfirst.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlDown

With targetSheet.Range(Cells(findfirst.Row - 2, 1), Cells(findfirst.Row - 2, 14))
    .Merge
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    .Font.Bold = 1
    .Font.Size = 18
    .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
    .Value = currentvalue
End With
Range("N1").Offset(1, 0).Value = Environ("Username")
```

***What I want***

My dataset in the first sheet.][
[image: My dataset in the first sheet.]

In the first sheet, I insert values under "Tykkelse [m]" in column H and "Radius [m]" in column J . So when I copy over, I want to create a headliner/row as above depending on if I insert a value in "Tykkelse [m]" or "Radius [m]" and if there are already a headliner/row to that, then copy the new copy right under the headliner/row.

This is happening right now.][
[image: This is happening right now.]

This is what I want.][
[image: This is what i want.]

In the pictures, you can see, what I get now with the code and what I want.

This is my current code in the modul and want to modify it that way, that it.

```
    Sub Copypastemeddata()
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartRow As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Opgørsel")
    Set sourceCell = ws.Range("D3")  'Cell with sheet names for copying to
    StartRow = 1    'Destination row on targetSheet
    With ws

          Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets(sourceCell.Text)
         .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
         targetSheet.Range("A" & StartRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
         targetSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
    Set findfirst = targetSheet.Range("H:H").Find("Tykkelse [m]")
        currentvalue = findfirst.Offset(1, -4).Value & " " & findfirst.Offset(1, 0).Value
        findfirst.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlDown

With targetSheet.Range(Cells(findfirst.Row - 2, 1), Cells(findfirst.Row - 2, 14))
    .Merge
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    .Font.Bold = 1
    .Font.Size = 18
    .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
    .Value = currentvalue
End With
Range("N1").Offset(1, 0).Value = Environ("Username")
End Sub
```

I hope that I have clearet out good and hope that some one can help me - Thank you beforehand :)

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary code to make the question concise and also point out which exact statement throws an error.

Comment: I hope it is better now, but when i run it, it says the error is in line 9 in the first code i uploaded - The first part wokred out finely, but when i put the code in as above in it to order it, it comes up with an error 9.

Comment: I found the error, the wasnt choosen any sheets - But it still dosent copy over the right way as i want with the added Picture?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Really,  i did it - instead of helping, you Guys are always sending me to other Places.

Comment: In stack overflow we want to create a list of questions and answers that other users can learn from. I want to help the community, not individuals. If you look at my previous answers, I have been helping out others who have put in the effort to ask a concise question where they are genuinely stuck even after trying a lot of stuff. Your question is too long with unnecessary deviations, it does not detail what you tried and how you failed. To give you a perspective, questions on VBA are always answered within 15 min, but most users have avoided your question because it is too lengthy and vague.

Comment: Thank you - Will do it better next time.

Comment: Another guy told me not to create a new question and edit this one, so i have done it now. I hope it is understandable now.

Comment: Did you seriously ask this question twice today, and 5 days ago as well?

Comment: No eaxctly the same question - I have tried and Watch a lot of videos, but cant come further.

Comment: This question is either very easy, very hard or nobody just dont want to help - i am stucked and it is a very hard task for me - I hope some of you can help.

Comment: Well, I've managed to get the code in `code markdown`. The problem was that you had numbered your points with "1" and "2". Normally, this is good writing. Unfortunately, the system thought you made a numbered list. I think the question is clear and has everything needed. It also shows what you've tried to solve it yourself. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - Glad to hear that and thank you for the voting.

Answer (score 0):

I'lltry something like this (using a loop to find 1.Altan 250):

```
Sub test1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sourceCell As Range
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

Dim fr, lr, nlr, llr As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Opgørsel")
Set sourceCell = ws.Range("D3")
Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets(sourceCell.Text)

targetSheet.Range("A1").Value = "1.Altan 150"
targetSheet.Range("A1").Font.Bold = 1
targetSheet.Range("A1").Font.Size = 16
targetSheet.Range("A1:K1").Interior.ColorIndex = 27
targetSheet.Range("A3").Value = "1.Altan 250"
targetSheet.Range("A3").Font.Bold = 1
targetSheet.Range("A3").Font.Size = 16
targetSheet.Range("A3:K3").Interior.ColorIndex = 27

If ws.Range("H3").Value = 150 Then

Do Until targetSheet.Cells(t, 1).Value = "1.Altan 250"
lr = t - 1
t = t + 1
Loop

ws.Rows("1:10").Copy
targetSheet.Rows(lr & ":" & lr).Insert Shift:=xlDown

ElseIf ws.Range("H3").Value = 250 Then

nlr = targetSheet.Range("A" & 100000).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Rows("1:10").Copy
targetSheet.Rows(nlr & ":" & nlr).Insert Shift:=xlDown

End If

targetSheet.Range("A1:K1").Merge

llr = targetSheet.Range("A" & 100000).End(xlUp).Row
targetSheet.Range("A" & llr & ":K" & llr).Merge

targetSheet.Range("N1").Offset(1, 0).Value = Environ("Username")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - Isnt it possible to let work with the current code? I do not know where to put it in. Instead of searching for "150" i want to search for the value in the first sheet and always referer to the targetsheet - I already have a copy for copying to the targetsheet, but want your "If" and "Elself" built in my current code.

Comment: I have modified a little bit the code to match your sheets names and references... hope it helps!